# Can one please elaborate the 'Engi Colony Hiding' encounter?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I've stumble the 'Engi Colony Hiding' encounter:

> You notice an **Engi colony hiding** on the other side of a nearby
>   moon. It turns out they're excavating an equipment cache from the
>   Federation-Mantis War, and they suggest it might be used to lure the
>   pursuing rebel fleet.

I can't seem to truly understand what are the options exactly (*and in a critical situation*):

> 1. **Booby** trap the cache (-2 missiles).
> 2. **Secure** the cache.

Can you please explain the story and the options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Engi_Colony_Hiding), here are the possible outcomes:

> 1. Booby trap the cache.
>
>    - *You transfer down some missile warheads and the Engi rig them to blow before setting a distress signal to attract the fleet's attention.*
>
>      - You lose 2 missiles and the Rebel Fleet is delayed for 2 turns.
> 2. Secure the cache.
>
>    - *You have the Engi complete their excavations and bring the supplies on-board.*
>
>      - You receive a medium amount of scrap and a drone.